# How can I block Accessibility services from controlling and seeing my app

Tags: android, accessibility

I have a security sensitive app that I want to protect from apps that use Accessibility services to control and read information inside apps.

How can I do this programmatically?

Comment: Are you really sure it is a good solution? Even if you are able to do that, there would be a number of users that wouldn't be able to use your app at all.

Comment: Other than using `FLAG_SECURE`, I am not aware of any options here. And, as Andre notes, this will have an impact on your user base.

Comment: I did find a workaround solution that uses accessibility delegate.  But this doesn't always work.  Thanks for the tip with using flags.  I'm gonna keep digging.  I know this will limit users but it is necessary for the app I'm building.